# Can everything that can be done with Pandas Dataframes be reproduced with Pyspark Dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I'm trying to think of a reason (other than you only have a small dataset) that you wouldn't use Pyspark Dataframes.

Can everything that can be done with Pandas Dataframes be reproduced with Pyspark Dataframes?

Are there some Pandas-exclusive functions or some functions that are incredibly difficult to reproduce with Pyspark?

Answer (score 1):

spark is a distributed processing framework. In addition to supporting the DataFrame functionality, it needs to run a JVM, a scheduler, cross-process/machine communication, it spins up databases, etc. So while of course, the answer to your question is no, not exactly everything is implemented the same way, the wider answer is that any distributed processing library naturally involves immense overhead. Lots of work goes into reducing this overhead, but it will never be trivial.

Dask (another distributed processing library with a [DataFrame](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/dataframe.html) implementation) has a great section on [best practices](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/best-practices.html). In it, the first recommendation is not to use dask unless you have to:

> Parallelism brings extra complexity and overhead. Sometimes it’s necessary for larger problems, but often it’s not. Before adding a parallel computing system like Dask to your workload you may want to first try some alternatives:
>
> - **Use better algorithms or data structures:** NumPy, Pandas, Scikit-Learn may have faster functions for what you’re trying to do. It may be worth consulting with an expert or reading through their docs again to find a better pre-built algorithm.
> - **Better file formats:** Efficient binary formats that support random access can often help you manage larger-than-memory datasets efficiently and simply. See the [Store Data Efficiently](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/best-practices.html#store-data-efficiently) section below.
> - **Compiled code:** Compiling your Python code with Numba or Cython might make parallelism unnecessary. Or you might use the multi-core parallelism available within those libraries.
> - **Sampling:** Even if you have a lot of data, there might not be much advantage from using all of it. By sampling intelligently you might be able to derive the same insight from a much more manageable subset.
> - **Profile:** If you’re trying to speed up slow code it’s important that you first understand why it is slow. Modest time investments in profiling your code can help you to identify what is slowing you down. This information can help you make better decisions about if parallelism is likely to help, or if other approaches are likely to be more effective.

There's a very good reason for this. In-memory, single-threaded applications are always going to be much faster for small datasets.

Very simplistically, if you imagine the single-threaded runtime for your workflow is T, the wall time of a distributed workflow will be `T_parallelizable / n_cores + T_not_parallelizable + overhead`. For pyspark, this overhead is very significant. It's worth it a lot of the time. But it's not nothing.